# Why does my React.js page go to the login redirection even though I am logged in?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to authorize my react.js page, I have generated a JWT in my ASP.CORE Web API and it is saving it in local storage correctly.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useUserContext } from "../UserContext";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");
  const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, userName, setUserName} = useUserContext();

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      const loginRes = await fetch("/api/Account/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: userName,
          password: password,
          returnUrl: "/",
        }),
      });
  
      if (loginRes.ok) {
        const data = await loginRes.json();
        console.log(data)


        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem('userId', data.userId);
        localStorage.setItem('userName', data.username);
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
        const userName = localStorage.getItem('userName');



        setSuccessMessage("Login Successful!");
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
        setTimeout( ()=> {
            navigate("/");
          }, 2000)

      } else {
        const data = await loginRes.json();
        console.error("Login failed", data);
        setError(data.message || "Failed to log in. Please try again.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during login:", error);
      setError("An error occurred during login. Please try again.");
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <>
      <form className="my-5 container" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <h1 className="m-5 text-center">Log in to your account...</h1>

        {successMessage && (
          <div className="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {successMessage}
          </div>
        )}

        {error && (
          <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {error}
          </div>
        )}

        <div className="mb-5 container">
          <label htmlFor="username" className="form-label">
            Your username
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control border-bottom"
            id="username"
            placeholder="Enter your username"
            value={userName}
            onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-5 container">
          <label htmlFor="password" className="form-label">
            Your password
          </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            className="form-control border-bottom"
            id="password"
            placeholder="Enter your password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="text-center">
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn customBtn text-light px-3 py-2"
            style={{ borderRadius: "0" }}
          >
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

This is how I've setup my Login page, and this is an example from my homepage. I only have an if statement here to check but I've tried other methods as well. What keeps happening is, I log into the account, and it redirects to the homepage. Once I refresh, it takes me back to the login page, even though I'm already logged in/the JWT token is saved in local storage. I even tried setting up a Protected Route but that gave the exact same result as here, and the same result that using a ternary operation did. I think the problem is with the condition but I'm not sure.
Btw, I've tested all my endpoints, they all return the correct response. The login endpoint returns the token, the user id and the username in the response body.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useUserContext } from "../UserContext";
import { AllBlogCard, HomeBlogCard } from "../components/AllBlogCard.jsx";
import Header from "../components/Header.jsx";
import Tag from "../components/Tag.jsx";

const HomePage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn } = useUserContext();
  const [blogPosts, setBlogPosts] = useState([]);
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const blogResponse = await fetch(
        "/api/Blog/List",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      if (!blogResponse.ok) {
        if (blogResponse.status === 401) {
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
          localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
          navigate("/login");
          return;
        } else {
          throw new Error("Failed to fetch blog data.");
        }
      }

      const tagResponse = await fetch("https://localhost:7242/api/Tag/List",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      const blogData = await blogResponse.json();
      const tagData = await tagResponse.json();

      


      setBlogPosts(blogData);
      setTags(tagData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("-----------COULDNT FETCH DATA: ", e.message);
      
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();

    if(!isLoggedIn){
      navigate("/")
    }

  }, [accessToken]);

  const latestBlogPost = blogPosts[0];
  const otherBlogPosts = blogPosts.slice(1);



  return (
    <>
      <Header
        title="ByteHub Blogs"
        subtitle="Unraveling the Tech Tapestry, One Insight at a Time..."
      />
      <div className="container mt-5 p-5">
        {loading ? (
          <h1 className="text-center">Loading..</h1>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div className="row">
              <HomeBlogCard {...latestBlogPost} />
            </div>

            <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center my-5">
              {tags.map((tag) => (
                <Tag
                  key={tag.id}
                  id={tag.id}
                  name={tag.name}
                  displayName={tag.displayName}
                />
              ))}
            </div>

            <div className="row">
              {otherBlogPosts.map((post, index) => (
                <div className="col-lg-3 col-12 mb-4" key={index}>
                  <AllBlogCard {...post} />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>

            <div className="text-center mt-4">
              <button className="btn customBtn my-5 text-light">
                View More Posts
                <i className="bi bi-arrow-down m-1"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: Please check the jwt token time and the server time? Or increase the expiration time of the token to 1 month.